# 5 Field Composite PK vs Surrogate PK

Tags: database, relational-database, primary-key, composite-key

I need to create a database that will be used by a zoo to keep track of their animals and employees etc. The only thing I need help with is the Service table which will be used to record services performed on an animal, for example, vaccination or health check up. The information that needs to be recorded is the employee who performed the service (assume only one employee is held responsible for each service), the animal being serviced, the service performed and the date/time it was performed.

My main issue is choosing between a composite PK shown in the first table and a surrogate PK shown in the second table. Could you give me your opinions on which design would be most suitable and the pros and cons of each approach.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
+-----------------------+
|  Service              |                     
+-----------------------+
| (PK)(FK1) animal_id   |
| (PK)(FK2) employee_id |
| (PK) service_type     |
| (PK) date             |
| (PK) time             |
+-----------------------+

+-------------------+
|  Service          |                     
+-------------------+
| (PK) service_id   |
| (FK1) animal_id   |
| (FK2) employee_id |
| service_type      |
| datetime          |
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

First, don't separate date and time into two columns. Call that *single* column "service_time".

If the set of columns {animal_id, employee_id, service_type, service_time} uniquely identifies a row, you *must* have a unique constraint on that set of columns regardless of whether you decide to use a surrogate key.  If you don't use a surrogate key, that constraint is usually declared as `primary key`. If you *do* use a surrogate key, that constraint is usually declared `unique`, with individual `not null` constraints on each column in that set.

If there aren't any tables that have foreign key references to *this* one, there's absolutely no point to creating an additional column as a surrogate key. And personally, I wouldn't use a surrogate key for this table even then. I know how to write a join. Most graphical query tools will do the join for you anyway.